# How do I save multiple audio files in a loop?

Tags: python, audio

I have multiple audio files which I have added white noise to using librosa. How do I save these new audio files in a loop now?

I used this article for the main computations: https://medium.com/@alibugra/audio-data-augmentation-f26d716eee66 and I have attached the rest of my code below. I don't know how to handle the last line in the for loop in this context. Assume that I have about 100 audio files.

```
path = "XXXXXX"
files = librosa.util.find_files(path, ext = ['wav'])
files = np.asarray(files)

a=AudioConfiguration()
for y in files:
    data = librosa.load(y, sr = 1600, mono = True)
    data = data[0]
    data_noise = a.add_noise(data)
    new_name = "output{1}.wav".format(filename)
    a.write_audio_file(new_name, data_noise)
```

**Update: Here's the solution**

```
for i in range (1, x):
    filename.write_audio_file("final_dataset/noise_%d.wav" %i, data_noise)
```

Comment: do you have the `write_audio_file` function in your code?

Comment: And where is `filename` given a value?